# How to use Laravel JSON API?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.8, json-api

I'm trying to use {JSON:API} with my Laravel app, and I can retrieve a list of records, but cannot access a single record.

I strictly followed the JSON:API tutorial (https://howtojsonapi.com/laravel.html), and I managed to run it and get the index list.

I used artisan to create all needed files : Adapter, Schema and Validator.

**json-api-v1.php :**

```
'resources' => [ 'titre' => App\Models\TitreModel::class, ];
```

**api.php :**

```
JsonApi::register('v1')->routes(function ($api, $router) {
        $api->resource('titre');
});
```

**TitreSchema.php :**

```
class TitreSchema extends SchemaProvider
{
    protected $resourceType = 'titre';

    public function getId($resource)
    {
    }

    public function getAttributes($resource)
    {
        return [
            'ID'      => $resource->ID,
            'ID_DICO' => $resource->ID_DICO,
        ];
```

**TitreAdapter.php :**

```
class TitreAdapter extends AbstractAdapter
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'ID'      => 'ID',
        'ID_DICO' => 'ID_DICO',
    ];

    protected $relationships = [];

    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

    public function __construct(StandardStrategy $paging)
    {
        parent::__construct(new TitreModel(), $paging);
    }
```

**TitreController.php :**

```
class TitreController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return new TitreCollection(TitreModel::paginate(parent::handlePerPage()));
    }

    public function show(TitreModel $titre)
    {   
        return new TitreResource($titre);
    }
```

When I visit **/api/v1/titre**, it's ok, I can get the json:api formatted records list.
But when I visit **/api/v1/titre/1**, I get this error :

```
"messages":{"count":1,"messages":[{"message":"[15:37:22] LOG.error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders() must be an instance of Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response, null given, called in C:\\www\\AppFlx\\dev\\dk_api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php on line 62
```

I'm the first to use JSON:API in my enterprise, so none of my colleagues can help me.
I only followed the tutorial, added nothing, changed nothing, and I don't use headers, so I don't get where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I found where it came from.

The problem came from **App\Exceptions\Handler.php**, with the render method.
Cause I made a simple copy-paste from the tutorial, and didn't check it.
The tutorial not-working **Handler** file :

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->isJsonApi($request, $e)) {
      return $this->renderJsonApi($request, $e);
    }

    // do standard exception rendering here...
}
```

Problem was I didn't add a return for standard exceptions.

The modified working **Handler** file :

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
  {
    return $this->renderJsonApi($request, $e);
  }
```

Works, since the method always have a return.